# Once and for all , whats up with doOnSubcribe

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

Consider the following observable chain

```
        Observable.just(1).
            doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Log.d("ThreadInDoSub", Thread.currentThread().getName())).
            subscribe();
```

Log reports the thread was main. This is okay. Now

```
Observable.just(1).
            doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Log.d("ThreadInDoSub", Thread.currentThread().getName())).
            subscribeOn(SchedulerProvider.getInstance().io()).
            observeOn(SchedulerProvider.getInstance().ui()).
            subscribe();
```

Log reports RxCachedThreadScheduler. Now

```
Observable.just(1).
        subscribeOn(SchedulerProvider.getInstance().io()).
        observeOn(SchedulerProvider.getInstance().ui()).
        doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Log.d("ThreadInDoSub", Thread.currentThread().getName())).
        subscribe();
```

Log reports main.

**Question**
Why does the location of doOnSub affect the thread it is being invoked on? . Isn't the whole chain executed upon hitting the subscribe method? . I am confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribeOn` calls `onSubscribe` on its downstream before scheduling the subscription to its upstream on the given scheduler, thus `doOnSubscribe` gets invoked on the thread where `subscribeOn` gets subscribed to. This is done so that the schedule can be cancelled more eagerly.

Comment: I apologize but i still dont understand it well. Why does the location of doonsubscribe matter in the chain?

Comment: Because RxJava is not the builder pattern where you configure an object. You apply operators that modulate the signal or control flow and there is a time component associated with them. Therefore, some signals happen before others inside operators thus moving them around will change the order in which they happen.

Comment: I always thought it is something akin to builders . This clears it up.